# Move objects at the beginning of array using sort()

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I need to sort an object array by date values:

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
})
```

But if `date` is undefined, it should be placed at the beginning. With my code shown above, the empty datasets will be placed at the end.

Comment: sounds like the quick and dirty would be to just reverse the array?... `array.sort(/* ...other code here... */).reverse()`

Comment: @MattOestreich No, as the sorting of all other elements should not be reversed

Comment: Gotcha.. well damn was hoping that would help..

Comment: What are the possible values for the date field? Is it expected to be string or integer?

Comment: @MisterJojo that's why I asked about the input. The Date constructor also supports strings

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak My dates are ISODate-strings

Comment: @user3142695  your choice is wrong because it doesn't work on Firefox

Comment: @MisterJojo What do you recommend?

Comment: See my answer below; otherwise gman has changed their response to correct this problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const array = [
  { date: 624000, name: 'Eddison', },
  { date: 224000, name: 'Bobby', },
  {               name: '--no date 2' },
  { date: 924000, name: 'Fred', },
  { date: 124000, name: 'Abe', },
  {               name: '--no date 1' },
  { date: 424000, name: 'David', },
  { date: 324000, name: 'Catheryn', },
];

// assuming there is no 0 date
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (a.date && b.date)
      ? new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)
      : (a.date || 1) - (b.date || 1); 
});

//result
array.forEach(elem => console.log(JSON.stringify(elem)));
```

note if you care about the difference between a date of 0 and a undefined date then

```
  return (a.date !== undefined && b.date !== undefined)
```

Comment: your a and b are numbers, no need to convert them to dates to make a sort...

Comment: Of course but the OP didn't show what their dates were and numbers work just fine as place holders for whatever they had.

Comment: Note that the OP clarified they have ISO date strings

Comment: I'm confused by this answer... Is it just me or are the objects without dates ***not*** at the ***end*** of what gets printed? In fact it doesn't seem like there is any sorting done at all?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak, the OP asked a wrong question made with unnecessary guessing

Comment: @MisterJojo agreed, and yet this simple and elegant solution solves the problem by addressing all possible variations. It may not be the most performant, i.e. in case we expected only numbers, but it will work with all viable inputs.

Comment: @MattOestreich The OP had an algorithm that would sort the objects from newest date to oldest, but null values would be considered the oldest because `new Date(null)` resolves to 1970. Instead OP asked how to move those undated objects to the front, i.e. to be considered the newest

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak thanks! I guess I'm still confused, because if you comment out this line `if (a.date === undefined) return -1;` it still returns the exact same results as when it isn't commented out... I am so confused lol.. It doesn't even appear as though any sorting at all is being done here?? I just rearranged the entire array and however it is instantiated, is how it gets logged/printed???

Comment: I guess there might be some semi-randomness involved. I am not sure why, but it probably is due to the sorting algorithm used. This can be different depending on browser.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak yep you are correct, I just tested in Chrome and it works.. This does not appear to work in Firefox.. whew, I was going crazy for a second there lol. Thank you so much for helping me grasp this!

Comment: it's a wrong anwser : b.date could also be undefined.

Comment: this code is OK on Chrome, but **wrong on FireFox**